# Compare two rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Question: I need to select only record with 'O' and also check the 'Actual Time' if record is 'D' then do not consider the record - 'O' output, see my expected output below (new to SQL)

```
SELECT DISTINCT Record, Actual Time  
FROM app.abc  
WHERE id = 100
```

```
Record      Actual Time
-----------------------------------
D           2022-06-13 02:52:00.000
O           2022-06-13 02:52:00.000
O           2022-06-13 05:11:00.000
```

Expected output:

```
Record   Actual Time
---------------------------------
O        2022-06-13 05:11:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

```
;WITH [X] AS (
SELECT DISTINCT [Record], [Actual Time]  FROM [app].[abc]  WHERE [id]=100 
)
SELECT
            O.[Record],
            O.[Actual Time]
    FROM
            [X] [O]
        LEFT JOIN
            (
            SELECT
                        [Actual Time]
                FROM
                        [X]
                WHERE
                        [Record] = 'D'         
            ) [D]
                ON D.[Actual Time] != O.[Actual Time]
    WHERE
            O.[Record] = 'O';
```

Comment: Thanks!, how about scenarios bases. The code works with combination of both - records 'D' AND 'O' where in if we have only single records with -'O' i need the result same or either if only  single record -  'D'

Comment: @Kamal, should have been a left join, I corrected.

Comment: If we add left join the first scenario of my question will release the combination record that is ( if record is 'D' then do not consider the record - 'O') :(

Comment: @Kamal, I don't understand. If there are no D records, what do you want as the result? If you want an answer that covers different cases, you should include those cases in the question, not in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find `O` records without a matching `D` record. That is pretty much the definition of an anti-join. You can do:

```
select a.*
from abc a
left join abc b on b.actual_time = a.actual_time and b.record = 'D'
where a.record = 'O' and b.record is null
```

Result:

```
record  actual_time
------  ---------------------------
O       2022-06-13 05:11:00.0000000
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/c9Dddl38).